# Why does my code duplicate only the first zero and not the others?

Tags: python, loops

Why does my code only duplicate the first zero and not the others?

```
def addzeros(a):
    c = a.count(0)
    while c>0:
        for i in a:
            if a[i] == 0:
                a.insert(a[i+1],0)
            return a
    
print(addzeros([1,0,2,0,7]))
```

Comment: try `for i in range(len(a))` instead of `for i in a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a function may only `return` once; once it returns, the function call is over. Also note that it is highly discouraged to alter a list while iterating through it.

Try defining an empty list instead and populating it while iterating through the old list:

```
def addzeros(a):
    c = a.count(0)
    b = []
    for i in a:
        if i == 0:
            b.extend((0, 0))
        else:
            b.append(i)
    return b
print(addzeros([1,0,2,0,7]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7]
```

Comment: why does 
for i in a:
        if i == 0:
this work and 
for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if a[i] == 0:
and this gives an error

Comment: @SairajDhonnar Because you altered the list while iterating through it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a python user, but it appears that your return statement is within your loop. Therefore, you will never loop through the whole array as it will return on its first usage. If this is wrong let me know I will delete, like I said I am not too familiar with python.